# Systematically extract noun arguments from J expression

Tags: refactoring, j, tacit-programming

What is the systematic approach to extracting nouns as arguments from an expression in J?  To be clear, an expression containing two literals should become a dyadic expression with the left and right arguments used instead of the literals.

I'm trying to learn tacit style so I prefer not to use named variables if it is avoidable.

A specific example is a simple die roll simulator I made:

```
   >:?10#6    NB. Roll ten six sided dice.
2 2 6 5 3 6 4 5 4 3
   >:?10#6
2 1 2 4 3 1 3 1 5 4
```

I would like to systematically extract the arguments 10 and 6 to the outside of the expression so it can roll any number of any sized dice:

```
   d =. <new expression here>
   10 d 6  NB. Roll ten six sided dice.
1 6 4 6 6 1 5 2 3 4
   3 d 100  NB. Roll three one hundred sided dice.
7 27 74
```

Feel free to illustrate using my example, but I'm looking to be able to follow the procedure for arbitrary expressions.

Edit: I just found out that a quoted version using x and y can be automatically converted to tacit form using e.g. `13 : '>:?x#y'`.  If someone can show me how to find the definition of `13 :` I might be able to answer my own question.

Comment: You mean something like `d =. 4 :'>:?x#y'`? ( or `d =. [: >: [: ? #` )

Comment: @Eelvex The latter please.  The derivation of the quoted definition is quite clear already, but I'd like to see how one gets from inline constants to a capped forks version in general.

Comment: Step 1: use primitives according to the vocabulary. Step 2: use [forks and hooks](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/09.htm) to create more complex verbs. Step 3: Use `@` and `&` for even more complex verbs.

Comment: Are you looking for a set of rules to follow in order to convert any explicit definition into a tacit one? If `13 :` can't do it every time, I'm pretty sure that there's some art to the conversion.

Comment: @Dane That is what I was looking for, but I may have been a bit naive.  It looks like it is unattainable in general but there are multiple useful procedures that work for many cases.  tangentstorm and algorithmshark have given me ample help for those cases. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your goal is to learn tacit style, it's better that you simply learn it from the ground up rather than try to memorize an explicit algorithm—[J4C](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/jforc/tacit_programs.htm) and [Learning J](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/learning/08.htm) are good resources—because **the general case of converting an expression from explicit to tacit is intractable**.

Even ignoring the fact that there have been no provisions for tacit conjunctions since J4, in the explicit definition of a verb you can (1) use [control words](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/ctrl.htm), (2) use and modify global variables, (3) put expressions containing `x` and/or `y` as the operands of an adverb or conjunction, and (4) reference itself. Solving (1), (3), or (4) is very hard in the general case and (2) is just flat out impossible.*

If your J sentence is one of a small class of expressions, **there is an easy way to apply the fork rules make it tacit**, and this is what is more or less what is implemented in `13 :`. Recall that

- `(F G H) y` is `(F y) G (H y)`, and `x (F G H) y` is `(x F y) G (x H y)` (*Monad/Dyad Fork*)
- `([: G H) y` is `G (H y)`, and `x ([: G H) y` is `G (x H y)` (*Monad/Dyad Capped Fork*)
- `x [ y` is `x`, `x ] y` is `y`, and both of `[ y` and `] y` are `y` (*Left/Right*)

Notice how forks use their center verbs as the 'outermost' verb: *Fork* gives a dyadic application of `g`, while *Capped Fork* gives a monadic one. This corresponds exactly to the two modes of application of a verb in J, monadic and dyadic. So a quick-and-dirty algorithm for making tacit a "dyadic" expression might look like the following, for `F G H` verbs and `N` nouns:

1. Replace `x` with `(x [ y)` and `y` with `(x ] y)`. (*Left/Right*)
2. Replace any other noun `n` with `(x N"_ y)`
3. If you see the pattern `(x F y) G (x H y)`, replace it with `x (F G H) y`. (*Fork*)
4. If you see the pattern `G (x H y)`, replace it with `x ([: G H) y`. (*Capped Fork()
5. Repeat 1 through 4 until you attain the form `x F y`, at which point you win.
6. If no more simplifications can be performed and you have not yet won, you lose.

A similar algorithm can be derived for "monadic expressions", expressions only dependent on `y`. Here's a sample derivation.

```
<. (y - x | y) % x                          NB. start
<. ((x ] y) - (x [ y) | (x ] y)) % (x [ y)  NB. 1
<. ((x ] y) - (x ([ | ]) y)) % (x [ y)      NB. 3
<. (x (] - ([ | ])) y) % (x [ y)            NB. 3
<. x ((] - ([ | ])) % [) y                  NB. 3
x ([: <. ((] - ([ | ])) % [)) y             NB. 4 and we win
```

This neglects some obvious simplifications, but attains the goal. You can mix in various other rules to simplify, like the long train rule—if `Train` is a train of odd length then `(F G (Train))` are equivalent `(F G Train)`—or the observation that `x ([ F ]) y` and `x F y` are equivalent. After learning the rules, it shouldn't be hard to modify the algorithm to get the result `[: <. [ %~ ] - |`, which is what `13 : '<. (y - x | y) % x'` gives.

The fail condition is attained whenever an expression containing `x` and/or `y` is an operand to an adverb or conjunction. It is sometimes possible to recover a tacit form with some deep refactoring, and knowledge of the verb and gerundial forms of `^:` and `}`, but I am doubtful that this can be done programmatically.

This is what makes (1), (3), and (4) hard instead of impossible. Given knowledge of how `$:` works, a tacit programmer can find a tacit form for, say, the [Ackermann function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ackermann_function) without too much trouble, and a clever one can even refactor that for efficiency. If you could find an algorithm doing that, you'd obviate programmers, period.

```
   ack1 =: (1 + ])`(([ - 1:) $: 1:)`(([ - 1:) $: [ $: ] - 1:)@.(, i. 0:)
   ack2 =: $: ^: (<:@[`]`1:) ^: (0 < [) >:
   3 (ack1, ack2) 3
61 61
   TimeSpace =: 6!:2, 7!:2@]  NB. iterations TimeSpace code
   10 TimeSpace '3 ack1 8'
2.01708 853504
   10 TimeSpace '3 ack2 8'
0.937484 10368
```

<sup>* This is kind of a lie. You can refactor the entire program involving such a verb through some advanced voodoo magic, cf. [Pepe Quintana's talk](http://www.2bestsystems.com/j/J_Conference_2012.rtf) at the [2012 J Conference](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Community/Conference2012). It isn't pretty.</sup>

Comment: A tacit verb can also reference itself or did I misunderstand `$:`?

Comment: @FUZxxl They can, which is why case (4) is not impossible, but refactoring arbitrary recursion to tacit form is not trivial. For instance, memoization (especially when you need something stronger than `M.`) is a nightmare.

Comment: Oh yes. I hate how `M.` is super unpredictable in when it chooses to memorize. I have the feeling that it measures execution time and memorizes when a certain threshold is surpassed but I might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`13 :` is documented in the [vocabulary](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm) or [NuVoc](http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Vocabulary/com) under `:` (Explicit).

The basic idea is that the value you want to be `x` becomes `[` and the value you want to be `y` becomes `]`. But as soon as the the rightmost token changes from a noun (value) to a verb like `[` or `]`, the entire statement becomes a train, and you may need to use the verb `[:` or the conjunctions `@` or `@:` to restore the composition behavior you had before.

You can also replace the values with the actual names `x` and `y`, and then wrap the whole thing in (`(dyad : ' ... ')`). That is:

```
>:?10#6    NB. Roll ten six sided dice.
```

can become:

```
10 (dyad : '>: ? x # y') 6  NB. dyad is predefined. It's just 4.
```

If you only need the `y` argument, you can use `monad`, which is prefined as `3`. The name `verb` is also `3`. I tend to use `verb :` when I provide both a monadic and dyadic version, and `monad` when I only need the monadic meaning.

If your verb is a one-liner like this, you can *sometimes* convert it automatically to tacit form by replacing the `3` or `4` with `13`.

I have some [notes on factoring verbs in j](http://tangentstorm.github.io/apljk/factoring-verbs-j.html) that can help you with the step-by-step transformations.

**addendum: psuedocode for converting a statement to tacit dyad**

This only covers a single statement (one line of code) and may not work if the constant values you're trying to extract are being passed to a conjunction or adverb.

Also, the statement must not make any reference to other variables.

- Append `[ x=. xVal  [ y =. yVal` to the statement.
- Substitute appropriate values for `xVal` and `yVal`.
- Rewrite the original expression in terms of the new `x` and `y`.
- rewrite `statement [ x=. xVal [ y=. yVal` as:

---

```
newVerb =: (4 : 0)
  statement ] y   NB. we'll fill in x later.
)
(xVal) newVerb yVal
```

Now you have an explicit definition in terms of `x` and `y`. The reason for putting it on multiple lines instead of using `x (4 : 'expr') y` is that if `expr` still contains a string literal, you will have to fiddle with escaping the single quotes.

**Converting the first noun**

Since you only had a pipeline before, the rightmost expression inside `statement` must be a noun. Convert it to a fork using the following rules:

- `y` → `(])`
- `x` → `]x ([)`
- `_`, `__`, `_9` ... `9` → `(_:)`, `(__:)`, `(_9:)` ... `(9:)`
- `n` → `n"_`    (for any other arbitrary noun)

This keeps the overall meaning the same because the verb you've just created is invoked immediately and applied to the `[ y`.

Anyway, this new tacit verb in parentheses becomes the core of the train you will build. From here on out, you work by consuming the rightmost expression in the statement, and moving it inside the parentheses.

**Fork normal form**

From here on out, we will assume the tacit verb we're creating is always a fork.

This new tacit verb isn't actually a fork, but we will pretend it is, because any single-token verb can be rewritten as a fork using the rule:

```
v → ([: ] v).
```

There is no reason to actually do this transformation, it's just so I can simplify the rule below and always call it a fork.

We will not use hooks because any hook can be rewritten as a fork with the rule:

(u v) → (] u [: v ])

The rules below should produce trains in this form automatically.

**Converting the remaining tokens**

Now we can use the following rules to convert the rest of the original pipeline, moving one item at a time into the fork.

For all of these rules, the `(]x)?` isn't J syntax. It means the `]x` may or may not be there. You can't put the `] x` in until you transform a usage of `x` without changing the meaning of the code. Once you transform an instance of `x`, the `]x` is required.

Following the J convention, `u` and `v` represent arbitrary verbs, and `n` is an arbitrary noun. Note that these include verbs

```
tokens y u (]x)? (fork) ] y  →  tokens   (]x)? (]  u fork) ] y
tokens x u (]x)? (fork) ] y  →  tokens    ]x   ([  u fork) ] y
tokens n u (]x)? (fork) ] y  →  tokens   (]x)? (n  u fork) ] y
tokens u v (]x)? (fork) ] y  →  tokens u (]x)? ([: v fork) ] y
```

There are no rules for adverbs or conjunctions, because you should just treat those as part of the verbs. For example  `+:^:3` should be treated as a single verb. Similarly, anything in parentheses should be left alone as a single phrase.

Anyway, keep applying these rules until you run out of tokens.

**Cleanup**

You should end up with:

```
newVerb =: (4 : 0)
  ] x (fork) ] y
)
(xVal) newVerb yVal
```

This can be rewritten as:

```
(xVal) (fork) yVal
```

And you are done.

Comment: Helpful general notes, but I am still coming up short of a general procedure.  Perhaps there is not one as `13 :` is not guaranteed to provide a tacit form. Do you happen to know how I can view the code/algorithm `13 :` uses (as opposed to its documentation)?

Comment: The J implementation is described in Hui's "An Implementation of J". There's a readable html version here: http://sblom.github.io/openj-core/ioj.htm ... Appendix D maps primitives to filenames containing their implementation. The bottom of cx.c appears to be where the left argument of `:` is mapped to a function, and a little digging indicates that the implementation is `jtvtrans` here: https://github.com/openj/core/blob/18fd23bbdc2f50770eb3047e978cd5e4e3b47039/pv.c#L223  ... I'm afraid understanding what that code does will take quite a bit of study.

Comment: I expanded my answer to include a (hopefully) complete algorithm in psuedocode.